# Electron flow in p-side of a diode

Tags: semiconductor-physics

There has been many posts with similar questions and great andwers, but I've not found an answer to my question, so either I am missing something or the simplified standard explanation doesn't cover it?

Im thinking purely in terms of wandering electrons in the conduction band of the n-side and the conductor that is connected to the diode, and "wandering holes"/electrons wandering through holes in the valence band of the p-side.

**My question**
I'm wondering why/how the electrons of a diode in forward bias can go from the valence band to the conduction band at the p-side of a diode where it's connected to a conductor and why this doesn't happen at the p-side to n-side connection in a diode when it's in reverse bias?

**Attempt to explain my question:**
In reverse bias, there's no free holes on the p-side and no free electrons on the n-side, so no electricity can flow.
But since the p-side is then negatively charged, the electrons in the now filled holes of the p-side would go into the conduction band and go to the n-side if they could. This doesn't happen, but isn't it exactly what happens at the p-side to conductor connection of a diode in forward bias?

Answer (score 1):

> and "wandering holes"/electrons wandering through holes in the valence band of the p-side.

Well don't do that. In the valence band only concern yourself with holes. Trying to reason through everything based on the underlying electrons will likely only create more confusion.

> But since the p-side is then negatively charged, the electrons in the now filled holes of the p-side would go into the conduction band and go to the n-side if they could.

You do have some charge carriers in the depletion region, contrary to what basic models would tell you. They are thermally generated and it is a relatively slow process. But it does occur and is one of the reasons that reverse bias current in a diode is not zero.

> This doesn't happen, but isn't it exactly what happens at the p-side to conductor connection of a diode in forward bias?

At the metal/semiconductor junction the generation and recombination rates are greatly increased. Unless you are concerned with the behavior of a Schottky diode you can typically assume generation and recombination are instantaneous at metal/semiconductor junctions. At these junctions electrons and holes are generated or recombined as needed in order to conduct electrons into or out of the metal.

At an n-type semiconductor and metal junction your majority carriers are already electrons, so you don't need much carrier reorganization. However, at a p-type semiconductor and metal junction, you either recombine a hole approaching the metal with an electron approaching the semiconductor, or you generate an electron/hole pair and they leave in opposite directions (electron into the metal and hole into the semiconductor)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This pretty much covers my questions.
It seems I wouldn't have struggled with these questions if we had covered band diagrams, but the class I'm taking is just a very basic electronics course, hence the unsatisfying model.
Thanks again.

Comment: Does this also mean that if you had the same amount of generation and recombination at the p-n junction as there is at the metal/semiconductor junction, the diode would conduct electricity in both biases?